# SSIS CSV Import Error 0xC0202092 DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

All of the sudden, a CSV file that is imported into a db/table every morning is failing every time within the last few weeks. I do not support this process directly, so I don't know much about SSIS, but would greatly appreciate some help as I need this working and whoever supports this process has no idea what the issue is. I'm not sure if that error regarding the row has anything to do with the data in the row because it looks fine to me. The CSV includes Active Directory information for every computer in AD and is exported from PowerShell to a server where the CSV is imported into a table via SSIS. The process is entirely automated and nothing has changed.

[Source - Clean_Gold CSV [1]] Error: The column delimiter for column "LastLogontimestamp" was not found.

[Source - Clean_Gold CSV [1]] Error: An error occurred while processing file "H:\Computers\clean_gold.csv" on data row 40377.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - Clean_Gold CSV" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: It would appear that the format of the CSV file has changed, so you should probably start by looking at the Powershell script that creates the CSV. The cause might be a change to your Active Directory schema. Have you inspected the CSV to check whether the format has changed (compared with earlier files)?

Comment: It also may be that a comma is missing somewhere on line 40377 have you inspected that line in the file?

Comment: ahh I was looking at 40,377 and didn't see anything, but then looked at 40,378 and saw someone put a ", in the description of the computer object in Active Directory. That caused an issue with the delimiting. Good to go now!

Answer (score 1):

I looked at 40,378 and saw someone put a ", in the description of the computer object in Active Directory. That caused an issue with the delimiting.